# How to use odometry provided by external Raspberry Pi device on Matek F405-WMN with Ardupilot?

Tags: flight-controller, raspberry-pi

I build device based on raspberry pi that calculates odometry for navigation without GPS. Now I want to test it in real conditions on drone. How can I do it in Ardupilot?

RPi calculates current coordinate relative to start point and current attitude few times a second and I need that Flight Controller used it instead of GPS.

I guess I should to communicate with F405 using some RX/TX pins by RPi GPIO, right? But in what format should I send data and how to process it in F405?

Maybe, I can use this for communication https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/raspberry-pi-via-mavlink.html but I don't understand how to use that data on flight controller.

Comment: Looks like I can base my solution on this https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/ros-slam.html